# Como configurar um domínio próprio no Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Comprei um domínio e preciso configurar junto a minha aplicação que está em Heroku. Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Para configurar o domínio da sua aplicação, é diretamente nas configurações da aplicação e acessando a seção "Domains". Olhando a documentação ([custom-domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)). Ele garante que requests feitos para o endereço customizado e que aponta para o endereço da sua aplicação no heroku (`xxxxxx.herokuapp.com`) sejam atendidos.

Você terá que configurar um CNAME ou ADDRESS (CNAME é mais confiável já que o seu domínio heroku nunca muda, o IP pode mudar dependendo da política do Heroku) do domínio que você quer para `xxxxxx.herokuapp.com` no seu provedor de DNS.

Acabei de fazer um teste: nas opções de "Domain" coloque apenas o endereço sem `www`, por exemplo: `nome_do_domino.com`. No seu provedor de DNS crie um registro de CNAME de `nome_do_domino.com` apontando para `nome_da_aplicacao.herokuapp.com`. Em pouco tempo o endereço fica acessível.

Comment: Opa, beleza @Wakim... vou testar aqui! Obrigado.

Comment: O problema do registro.br é não ter suporte de asterisco no `CNAME` `*.bar.com.br`, outra alternativa é usando IP fixo no `A` porém com Heroku, o IP fixo é mais complicado ainda, inicialmente só oferece pelo endereço. Como fica?

Answer (score 1):

Enquanto utilizar o método `nome-do-app.herokuapp.com` funciona, o ACM (Gerenciador de Certificados Automáticos) do Heroku irá falhar e você **não** irá conseguir utilizar seu domínio com uma sessão HTTPS, apenas HTTP. Para que o ACM não falhe, você precisará usar o *DNS target*.

Como eu demorei pra achar uma solução e essa pergunta foi uma das que surgiram quando eu pesquisei no Google, decidi postar o que aprendi para poder ajudar quem está perdido. Além disso, as respostas dadas anteriormente não resolvem *completamente* o problema em 2020.

Aqui vou tentar ser o mais completo possível fazendo um passo a passo, mas **a resposta direta para a pergunta está no Passo 4**. Se o local que você comprou o domínio tem suporte para *records* tipo `ANAME` ou `ALIAS`, pode pular os passos 1 e 2.

### Passo 0: eu preciso do PointDNS?

**Depende**. Você pode sim usar o próprio servidor DNS que o caso ele forneça suporte para *records* de tipo `ANAME`/`ALIAS`, pois o Heroku exige isso para domínios root. Sem isso, apesar de você poder usar o `www` (ex.: `https://www.meu-dominio.com`), não poderá usar o root do seu domínio (ex.: `https://meu-dominio.com`). Atualmente muitas pessoas não digitam mais o `www` no início e, apesar de alguns navegadores modernos colocarem o prefixo automaticamente, você corre o risco do seu visitante digitar e não conseguir acessar seu site.

Se só quiser registrar o `www` e não quiser utilizar o PointDNS, pule para o **passo 3**.

### Passo 1: habilitando o add-on do PointDNS

Para configurar corretamente o ACM juntamente com o PointDNS você precisa adicionar esse add-on em pelo menos um dos seus apps. Note que, **não necessariamente você precisa configurar o PointDNS para o app que ele está conectado e pode direcionar subdomínios para outros apps**. Como experiência pessoal, eu tenho o add-on no meu app de produção e também uso-o para configurar o domínio de *staging*.

Para configurar:

- Pela UI: Entre na aba *Resources*; na parte de *add-ons*, pesquise por *PointDNS* no campo de busca e selecione o resultado que tiver o plano *Developer*.
- Pelo CLI: digite o comando: `heroku addons:create pointdns:developer`.

Este plano é gratuito e permite 10 *records* com 10.000 redirecionamentos mensais (mais que o suficiente para um projeto pessoal).

### Passo 2: modificando os nameservers do local de registro

Se você ainda não fez isso, sem problemas, façamos agora.

Antes de entrar na sua conta de onde registrou seu domínio, veja a [lista de Nameservers no app do PointDNS](https://app.pointhq.com/nameservers) (você precisará estar logado) e escolha os 3 que possuírem melhor localização (no momento que escrevo eles recomendam 3). Adicione esses 3 escolhidos na lista de *records* com tipo `NS`.

Agora entrando na sua conta, procure as configurações e siga os passos (baseado no registro.br):

1. Clique no domínio da lista que deseja editar.
2. Na seção de DNS, clique em `Alterar Servidores DNS`.
3. Coloque 1 master e 2 slaves com os 3 nameservers que você escolheu no PointDNS.
4. Salve tudo e, **importante, aguarde por pelo menos 2 horas para que essas mudanças se propaguem**.

### Passo 3: adicionando um domínio no Heroku

Caso você já não tenha feito isso antes, esse sim você precisará adicionar no app que irá utilizar no Heroku. Para adicionar, utilize:

- Pela UI: Entre na aba *Settings*; na parte de *domains*, clique em *Add domain*. Digite seu domínio e clique em *next*. Copie o DNS target que aparecerá, você precisará dele depois.
- Pelo CLI: digite o comando: `heroku domains:add www.example-domain.com`. Depois, digite o comando `heroku domains` e copie o DNS target que aparecerá, você precisará dele depois.

**Obs. 1:** O DNS target será algo no formato `papagaio-brasileiro-13fqwefrr4r.herokudns.com` ou algo parecido que termine em `.herokudns.com`

**Obs. 2:** Lembre-se que `meu-dominio.com` e `www.meu-dominio.com` são 2 *records* diferentes e, caso queira abranger ambas as grafias dos usuários, você precisará registrar ambos.

### Passo 4: adicionando os DNS targets no PointDNS (válido para qualquer outro serviço de DNS)

Se você tiver usando o PointDNS e já tiver passado pelo **passo 3**, provavelmente ao acessar a interface você já verá alguns *records* escritos automaticamente. Apesar deles serem válidos para acessar o site, não irão funcionar com o ACM (Gerenciador Automático de Certificados). Para isso você deve utilizar os DNS targets que eu falei que iria precisar no **passo 2**.

1. Para acessar o Dashboard do PointDNS, vá na UI do Heroku, na aba *Resources* e clique no *add-on* do PointDNS.
2. **No Dashboard do PointDNS, clique no lápis para editar o *record* e adicione o respectivo *DNS target* no campo *target/data*, substituindo o que tiver lá.**
3. Você pode adicionar novos *records* para outros apps caso deseje utilizar outro subdomínio do mesmo domínio. Para isso clique em *Add record*, selecione o tipo correto, coloque o subdomínio e o respectivo *DNS target* no campo *target/data*.
4. Uma vez que todas as modificações forem feitas, **aguarde por pelo menos 2 horas para que essas mudanças se propaguem**.

**Obs:** Para domínio *root* (ou seja, sem o `www.` na frente, somente `meu-dominio.com`) você precisa **obrigatoriamente** usar o tipo `ALIAS` ao configurar o *record*. **NÃO UTILIZE O TIPO CNAME PARA DOMÍNIOS ROOT.** Para todos os outros *records* que possuam subdomínio (`www`, `staging`, etc), utilize o tipo `CNAME`.

### Passo 5: ufa... acabou!

Somente **aguarde por pelo menos 2 horas** para que essas mudanças se propaguem. Parece besta, mas eu mesmo errei muito nessa parte. Quando as mudanças estiverem concluídas, o ACM irá automaticamente validar os certificados SSL e você não precisará se preocupar mais com isso.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que o "naked domain" (xxx.com.br) não pode ser um CNAME. O que pode ser feito é 
1) Criar um CNAME de www.xxx.com.br para nome_da_aplicacao.herokuapp.com
2) Colocar uma entrada A apontando para 174.129.25.170

Esse IP é de um serviço que redireciona domínios sem www para www.dominio , mais detalhes nesta URL:

http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect